# Rails: mostly has_one / sometimes has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is probably a newbie question, but I cannot figure out the best solution.
I have a `Color` model and a `Cover` model.
Most of the time, a cover `has_one :color`. Maybe one out of one hundred cases, the cover `has_many :colors`.
Do I have to implement a `has_many :through` association between the two models? It seems redundant. What's the best practice to define such a relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should cover the general case, when `Cover has_many :colors`. So this is a many-to-many relationship. In this case, you will have 2 options:

1. Use **join table**, if you just need to store `cover_id` and `color_id` in the join table, so you will use `has_and_belongs_to_many` to define your association. With this option, You will have to create join table.
2. Use **join model**, if you need to store not only `cover_id` and `color_id`, but also other attributes, and you need to do some calculation, so you have to use `has_many :through` to define your association. With this option, You will have to create new model.

Answer (score 0):

Cover `has_many :colors` would be best way, even if there is only one single case that requires it.

Comment: Color also `has_many :covers`, thus it becomes a many-many association. Do I need to create a new `Relationship` model and implement `has_many :through`?